# What screw should be used to secure plywood blocking into metal studs?

Tags: walls, screws, metal, hanging, framing-fasteners

I’m opening a wall to add some 3/4 plywood blocking. Something similar to this picture.

What screw should I use considering I’m going from metal to wood? Something that is rust resistant and strong enough since the idea here is to hang a small network rack that may be over 100lbs (after the wall is closed).

[image]

Some additional details for those wondering what and why - this is the rack:

https://www.penn-elcom.com/us/17-3-4in-deep-9u-white-wall-mount-rack-with-10-32-threaded-rails-and-poly-front-door-r6409w-1032

[image]

According to the documentation, the rack alone is 55 lbs, I’m assuming another 50 for the equipment.

Dimensions: 20 H x 23 1/2 W
The wall mount brackets are 20 1/2 W

This is a rough idea of what I’m planning:

[image]

And this close up should give a better idea of how the plywood board is attached to the studs:

[image]

Image extracted from: https://frtw.com/?page_id=144

Comment: Do the rack's mount holes miss the studs? By "small" do you mean narrower than the stud spacing. If it's wider and the mount holes miss, can you possibly add holes to the rack? Maybe a couple of aluminum bar beams (or painted steel ones) can join it to the studs and still look nice?

Comment: This is an odd place - corner. There are 3 studs, which means two wood blocks. The first 2 studs are 24 inches apart, and the third one at 16 inches from the first. The rack is less than 24” wide but to have it exactly where I want, it will have to be attached to both wood blocks, missing the first and third stud. I hope it makes sense. What kind of aluminum bar are you referring to? Would it support a bit over 100 lbs? I initially thought about opening the wall and add a large (maybe 3 feet high) plywood blocking because I thought it was too much weight.

Comment: Something like https://alcobrametals.com/aluminum/structural-aluminum-angle-equal-leg/ or https://alcobrametals.com/aluminum/aluminum-rectangular-flat-bar-extruded/6061-aluminum-flat-bar/. That particular grade of aluminum has similar strength to mild steel (A36 steel). I would have to see the rack and have a better understanding of the dimensions involved (wall and rack) to prescribe something specific. Eccentricity of the rack's weight from the wall is relevant also. Better: _Studs are at 3", 11", and 27" from the corner. Rack goes at 5" and 22"_...or maybe a drawing or image w/ dimensions.

Comment: I add some info the post. But this bar is an L shape, I thought you meant something flat.

Comment: the second link is bar, but bar is weak if it's getting pulled away from the wall. The L shape has better strength pulling away from the wall, where your eccentric loading would could be handled at probably 20% or so of the cost using angle instead of bar.

Comment: I see, if the plan is to avoid opening the wall we would have to use a bar but I’m guessing it would have to be a thick one, which would bring the same aesthetics issue as having the plywood outside the wall.

Comment: I tried to make it work for Snaptoggle anchors at the mount bar screw positions, but they don't quite work. Or they kinda do, but it's too close for comfort given all of the assumptions I'm making (like how to handle combined tension and shear for a drywall anchor). I'm pretty confidant that Snaptoggle anchors can work with flat head bolts (with the conical heads). It would require fabricating aluminum bars with countersunk holes, however, and I'm skeptical that you're so desperate to avoid breaking into the wall that you would bother with all of the complexity and tooling cost.

Answer (score 2):

For a network rack ~100 lbs I think this is overkill. Not the plywood - that's perfect. But opening up the wall is just not necessary, and it means a lot of extra work to patch the drywall.

In addition, you may open up the wall and find that the metal studs are mounted in a way that you can't actually install wood *through* them as shown in the picture.

- Find the studs.
- Place the plywood over the existing drywall, which is over the studs. Use some screws around the plywood to temporarily hold it in place.
- Drill pilot holes in the plywood.
- Drive screws through plywood and drywall into the studs.

Any screw designed for wood + steel will do the job. A quick search found [this page from Simpson](https://www.strongtie.com/screwsandnails_fasteningsystems/category?v=:relevance:featureApplicationMenuFacet:Fastening+Wood-to-Steel) but there are plenty of other options.

The plywood can be painted before mounting so that it matches the wall and equipment rack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought about it but this will be in my laundry room and wife thinks the exposed plywood will make it look weird :-) I had to expend some extra money on a white rack just so it can match the other cabinets so… you get the point :-)

Comment: Two coats of white paint on the plywood before you mount it will be a lot easier than a full patch/paint of the drywall.

Comment: Heat and humidity and lint and electronics! Good combo if you sell electronics, less good if you buy them. ;^)

Comment: @Ecnerwal True. But if the laundry room is reasonably well ventilated, and in particular if the dryer is properly vented to the outside, then this really shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When I clean a laundry room with a dryer vent going outside, somehow there's always plenty of lint around anyway...

Comment: I got you. Or my machine and installation are really good or.. really bad because I don’t see any lint around. I’ve been monitoring the room for a few months now and the temperature and humidity is always the same as the rest of the house, that may have something to do with the size of the room and the AC vent we have there. I think I’m good here but I will add some temperature sensors to the rack just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The screws should be calibrated to the material at the back of the connection, wood in this case. They should be long enough to stick out the back of the plywood. There's a risk of overtightening to tear the plywood (in contrast against sawn lumber studs which won't tear with typical screw lengths). 3/4" isn't very thick in comparison to the 3-1/2" studs for which most of us have a good intuition, so I would double my 3-1/2" stud intuition's screw count.

Use exterior screws or anything hot dip galvanized if corrosion is a potential problem. Non-bearing studs typically have minimal corrosion protection, so this part of your question seems a bit silly.

Comment: That is great advice, you right, I should be looking at wood screws, makes perfect sense. It’s an inside wall so the corrosion part may be me overthinking things. You mentioned 3 1/2 sawn lumber. Do you think I should go for something stronger/thicker than plywood for this?

Comment: @Ebrito, it depends on the geometry involved. As the rack's center of gravity moves away from the wall, the exact geometry of the anchorages becomes important. As that center of gravity moves away, the withdrawal load in the fasteners increases. For non-trivial withdrawal load and if the rack doesn't have an extra mount hole or two for redundancy, I would probably install tee nuts on the backside of the plywood and bolt to the plywood. But now I'm making assumptions about how exactly you intend to get the plywood in there.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. The rack is 17” deep and the equipment stays in the front of the rack so it may add a lot of tension on the screws. I thought of using snaptoggles to secure both, the plywood to the metal studs and the rack mounting. Brackets to the plywood. The heavy duty ones: https://toggler.com/products/snaptoggle-heavy-duty-toggle-bolts-304-stainless-steel-channels